# Equality of Transformation of a Random Variable

Tags: distributions, random-variable

I'm having trouble proving something I'm reading in a research paper, and wanted to get some other thoughts:

Suppose we define the transformation $\psi : [-\infty, \infty] \times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ given by
$$ \psi(x,u) = P[X<x] + uP[X=x] $$
Consider also the lexicographical order
$$ (x,u) \preceq (x^*,u^*) \Leftrightarrow (x<x^*) \cup (x=x^* \cap u\leq u^*) $$

It is proved in the paper that
$$ P[\psi(X,U) \leq \psi(x,u)] = P[(X,U) \preceq (x,u)] $$

---

The part I don't understand is the following: If $T$ is strictly increasing and continuous on the range of $X$, then $$ \psi(T(X),U) = \psi(X,U) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ [1] $$

What I have worked out so far is the following.  Suppose we define $X^* := \psi(X,U)$ and $X_T^* := \psi(T(X),U)$.  Then, the claim that the paper is making the transformed random variables are equivalent, meaning that the following statement should be true: $$P[X^* \leq z] \overset{?}{=} P[X_T^* \leq z] \ \ \ \ \forall \ z$$, where $z := \psi(x,u)$.  This means, we can do the following simplifications:
$$\begin{align} 
 P[\psi(X,U) \leq \psi(x,u)] &\overset{?}{=}  P[\psi(T(X),U) \leq \psi(x,u)] \\ 
= P[(X,U) \preceq (x,u)] &\overset{?}{=}  P[(T(X),U) \preceq (x,u)] \\
= P[X<x] + P[X=x]P[U\leq u] &\overset{?}{=} P[T(X)<x] + P[T(X)=x]P[U\leq u] \\ 
= P[X<x] + P[X=x]P[U\leq u] &\overset{?}{=} P[X<T^{-1}(x)] + P[X=T^{-1}(x)]P[U\leq u]
\end{align}$$

This is as far as I've gotten mathematically.  If I assume that X is a continuous random variable, then we know that $P[X=x] = P[T(X)=x] = 0$, and the expression simplifies to
$$P[X<x] \overset{?}{=} P[X<T^{-1}(x)] $$
I don't think the equality is satisfied here ... any ideas?  Does Equation 1 become valid if X is a discrete random variable rather than continuous?

Comment: Could you tell us what "$U$" is?  It seems it ought to be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$, independent of $X$, but you haven't actually said anything about it.

Comment: @whuber , I'm sorry, yes you are correct, $U$ is a uniform random variable and independent of $X$. In the spirit of providing more information, it should also be noted that the transformation $\psi$ defined above is in the context of this paper applied to discrete random variables so that the transformed random variable $\psi(X,U)$ is uniformly distributed.  However, the section I am referring to doesn't explicitly state that $X$ has to be discrete, and hence I used $X$ being continuous as what I think is a counter-example.

Comment: If $X$ is continuous then $\Pr(X=x)=0$.  How could that possibly lead to a counterexample? You are getting lost in a vague notation and winding up with something that makes no sense.

Comment: @whuber Right, if X is continuous, then as you and I both stated, $Pr(X=x)=0$, and thus we are left to see if $Pr(X<x)$ equals $P(X<T^{-1}(x))$ to make Equation 1 true.  There must be some misunderstanding on my part here because the only way I see those two being equal is if $x$ equals $T^{-1}(x)$, but that is not true in general, correct?

Comment: I believe the misunderstanding may begin with your introduction of $T$ (which you never explicitly define, btw).  There seems to be a great potential for confusing real values with random variables.

Comment: @whuber The only information I have about $T$ in the paper is that $T$ is strictly increasing and continuous on ran $X$.  I've been assuming that because it is defined in this way, $T$ is a deterministic strictly increasing function.  The paper also says that $F_{T(X)}(x) = F_X(T^{-1}(x))$, which also leads me to believe that $T$ is a deterministic function.  Is that what you were getting at with regards to confusing real variables and random values?  I'm still not sure how that helps?

Comment: It's still a total mystery what $T$ might be.  Certainly if it's just an increasing continuous function, it's not the case that $\psi(T(X),U)=\psi(X,U)$.  Is this equation $[1]$ actually asserted in the paper or is it something you came up with?

Comment: @whuber Equation [1] is asserted in the paper.  The exact "proof" from the paper is written as: "First note that the distribution function of $T(X)$ is given by $F_{T(X_1)}(x) = F_X(T^{-1}(x))$ if T is increasing.  One easily shows that this leads to $(\psi(T(X),U) = \psi(X,U)$."  For reference, the paper is http://www.actuaries.org/ASTIN/Colloquia/Zurich/Neslehova.pdf and the Proof is in Section 4.  The asserted Equation [1] appears in Corrolary 6, #2.

Comment: If that's the case, then the notation is utterly confused. After all, it is a simple matter to apply the definition of $\psi$, substituting $T(X)$ for $x$ and $U$ for $u$, to obtain $\psi(T(X),U)=\Pr(X\lt T(X))+U\Pr(X=T(X))$, which obviously is not what was intended.

Comment: @whuber I agree with you, the notation in this paper is quite confusing.